# CT Sensors with Arduino and ESP32

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32

there. I am following this tutorial to build an energy monitor system.
The link is https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/ct-sensors/interface-with-arduino
Everything works fine with an Arduino UNO on ADC A1, but I need to send the data to a WebServer, so I decided to do the same setup with ESP-WROOM-32 which has a wifi module. I read the value from pin 34, the code I am using is following

```
// EmonLibrary examples openenergymonitor.org, Licence GNU GPL V3

#include "EmonLib.h"                   // Include Emon Library
EnergyMonitor emon1;                   // Create an instance

void setup()
{  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  emon1.current(34, 111.1);             // Current: input pin, calibration.
}

void loop()
{
  double Irms = emon1.calcIrms(1480);  // Calculate Irms only
  Serial.println(Irms);            // Irms
}
```

The current is always 0, when I add a println(analogRead(34)), it always gives me back the maximum number 4095. I am confused when it is not working with the ESP32 but with Arduino UNO, the power supply for both is 3.3V.
[image]
[image]

Can someone help me, please? Thank you so much!

Comment: it looks like you're feeding the orange ADC wire with 3.3v from the white wire. measure from row 60?

Comment: Your R2 doesn't seems to be connect to the mid-point. Also the library you are using `EmoLib` doesn't work for ESP32 as the formula and assumptions it used in the library is wrong for ESP32. Try [EmonLib-ESP32](https://github.com/Savjee/EmonLib-esp32) which fix the library and make it works for ESP32.

Comment: @hcheung Hi, the circuit on the breadboard working fine with the Arduino UNO, I don't think there are any connection issues, but I will try to use that library, thank you so much!

Comment: @hcheung If you zoom in on the 33R load resistor you can just see a tiny bit of yellow peeking through that looks like it might be the "missing link" on the R2 midpoint resistor.

Comment: @Majenko Hi, Can you see the answer I posted? I took the picture with a different angle this time

Comment: Since you did not post a link to the hardware I will take a SWAG. Many of the ESP32s have a max of 1 volt on the analog to digital converter. You will need to check your data sheet for that. I would also be sure you limit the current into the A/D so you do not blow it.